# Haskell: Data type containing other Data Types

Tags: haskell

if I have two data structures

```
data Tri = Tri {a :: Int, b :: Int , c :: Int} deriving Show
data Quad = Quad {w :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int, z :: Int} deriving Show
```

how do I create another data structure made up of those two? ie something alon the lines of:

```
data Shape = Tri | Quad derivng Show
```

Comment: Something as simple as `type Shape = Either Tri Quad` might suffice.

Answer (score 10):

You have to give names to data constructors:

```
data Shape = ShapeTri  { shapeTri  :: Tri }
           | ShapeQuad { shapeQuad :: Quad } 
                 deriving Show
```

Answer (score 4):

@talex's answer is correct. Here are some variations (mainly just different syntax).

Without record syntax:

```
data Shape = ShapeTri Tri | ShapeQuad Quad 
  deriving Show
```

It may make more sense to combine Shape, Tri, and Quad:

```
data Shape = Tri  {a :: Int, b :: Int , c :: Int} 
           | Quad {w :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int, z :: Int}
  deriving Show
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to keep them separate is because I wanted to write different instances for them. Is there a better way for that?

Comment: Might I ask what instances you are writing for `Tri` and `Quad`?

Comment: to be honest that is not the actual code, I just used those as an example. The last example you wrote seems the easiest to use

Comment: I definitely recommend against combining them. All the record accessors `a`, `b`, ... become partial functions that blow up if you use them on the wrong constructor